# DataGrid bind to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, observablecollection

I'm trying to bind an ObservableCollection on my ViewModel to a DataGrid on my view:

```
public class RequestListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Request> requests;
    private Timer uTimer;
    public RequestListViewModel()
    {
        requests = RequestAction.getRequestList();
        SetRequestsUpdateTimer();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Request> Requests
    {
        get { return requests; }
        set { requests = value; OnPropertyChanged("Requests"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

This ObservableCollection is updated with a timer and is working fine. The data is updated. The problem is that update is not reflected on the view side:

```
<DataGrid Name="lstRequests" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" GridLinesVisibility="None" MouseDoubleClick ="myDataGrid_MouseDoubleClick" 
                  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
...

            </DataGrid.Columns>
```

And I create the binding like this:

```
public RequestListView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    model = new RequestListViewModel();
    //this.DataContext = model;
    lstRequests.ItemsSource = model.Requests;
    Binding myBinding = new Binding();
    myBinding.Source = model;
    myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Requests");
    myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
    lstRequests.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding);
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why not just bind in XAML?

Comment: I tried but I should also missing something more there, because when I do that I don't get any data. What is the XAML equivalent?

Comment: Well, you can't set the `Source` that easily, but usually you don't do that and use the implicit `DataContext`.

Comment: how i do that? sorry, I'm new at WPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would only set `DataContext` if anything in code:

```
this.DataContext = model;
```

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Requests}" ... />
```

`TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger` is non-sense and does not apply for `ItemsSource`. If you change the `DataContext` along the hierarchy this binding will of course fail. Also, if you switch out your model completely and do not update the `DataContext` the binding will also no longer update.

---

From the comments it seems clear your problem is that you are misusing your code. Usually i prevent this whenever i use `ObeservableCollections` by making it read and get-only:

```
private readonly ObeservableCollection<...> _field = new ObeservableCollection<...>();
public ObeservableCollection<...> Property { get { return _field; } }
```

Comment: That should be enough, really. Do you get the items displayed at least once?

Comment: Yes, the first time. Then the other times is not updated

Comment: What I'm doing with the timer is updating that:

requests = RequestAction.getRequestList();

Comment: Then your timer is doing something wrong, like replacing the field without using the property, hence circumventing a call to `PropertyChanged`.

Comment: You were right! I was updating by the field instead of the proprety. Thanks for the help!